# Spring boot controller not getting scanned error 404 not found

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create restful api but my controller is not working and I'm  getting the error shown below:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-11T15:28:18.103+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/path/findCarsAfterYear/2020"
}
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Entity Class

```
    package com.example.demo.data;

    import javax.persistence.*;

    @Entity
    public class Car {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column
        private long id;

        @Column
        private String model;

        @Column
        private Integer year;

        // standard getters and setters


        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getModel() {
            return model;
        }

        public void setModel(String model) {
            this.model = model;
        }

        public Integer getYear() {
            return year;
        }

        public void setYear(Integer year) {
            this.year = year;
        }
    }
```

Repository Class

```
    package com.example.demo.Repository;
    import com.example.demo.data.Car;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

    import java.util.List;

    @Repository
    public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Integer> {


        @Query("Select wds from Car wds where year=?1 ")
        List<Car> findCarsAfterYear(Integer year);


    }
```

Service class

```
    package com.example.demo.service;

    import com.example.demo.Repository.CarRepository;
    import com.example.demo.data.Car;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    @Service
    public class CarService {



        @Autowired
        CarRepository carRepository;



        public List<Car> findCarsAfterYear(Integer id) {
            return carRepository.findCarsAfterYear(id);
        }





    }
```

Controller class

```
    package com.example.demo.Controller;

    import com.example.demo.data.Car;
    import com.example.demo.service.CarService;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import java.util.List;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(path="/test")

    public class CarController {
        @Autowired(required=true)

        private CarService carService;
        @GetMapping(value="/findCarsAfterYear/{id}")
        public List<Car> findCarsAfterYear(Integer id) {
            return carService.findCarsAfterYear(id);

        }
    }
```

Application Class

```
    package com.example.demo;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

    @Configuration
    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.demo.Repository")
    @EntityScan("com.example.demo.data")
    @ComponentScan(basePackages="com.example.demo.service,com.example.demo.Controller")
    @EnableCaching

    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried with url `/test/findCarsAfterYear/2020` ? Also if you have provided any `context-path` in .property file then try with `../context-path-value/test/findCarsAfterYear/2020`.

Comment: Yes i already tried this http://localhost:8080/test/findCarsAfterYear/2020. no i havent provided any context path in property file

Comment: see this error  Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]
2020-06-11 17:18:49.576 DEBUG 22800 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2020-06-11 17:18:49.577 DEBUG 22800 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2020-06-11 17:18:49.577 DEBUG 22800 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

Comment: Replace `@Controller` with `@RestController`

Comment: I were able to resolve by adding  scan base package and 
 commenting all other scan @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class},scanBasePackages = "com.example.demo")    and by adding  public @ResponseBody List<Car> findCarsAfterYear(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return carService.findCarsAfterYear(id);

Answer (score 0):

In you want to use `@Controller` then you have to provide `@ResponseBody` explicitly.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path="/test")
public class CarController {
    @Autowired(required=true)

    private CarService carService;
    @GetMapping(value="/findCarsAfterYear/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Car> findCarsAfterYear(Integer id) {
        return carService.findCarsAfterYear(id);

    }
}
```

But in case `@RestController`, which is combination of `@Controller`and `@ResponseBody`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/test")
public class CarController {
    @Autowired(required=true)

    private CarService carService;
    @GetMapping(value="/findCarsAfterYear/{id}")
    public List<Car> findCarsAfterYear(Integer id) {
        return carService.findCarsAfterYear(id);

    }
}
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: When I am using RestoController without Responsebody it is returning blank result. 
Result []

Comment: try debuging `findCarsAfterYear()` where actual list is empty or not? but Are you getting result with `Controller` and `ResponseBody` ?

Comment: Yes  I am getting result with Controller and ResponseBody

Comment: looks a bit strange to me. try debugging `findCarsAfterYear()` in case of `RestController`